# How to remove fix text trigger on right side in browser?

Tags: jquery, scrollmagic

How to remove fix text trigger on right side in browser?

I searched in Google. Someone tell to remove scene.addIndicators() but when I remove that the scroll is gone.

This is screenshot

[image]

This is my code

```
                <script>
                    // define images
                    var images = [
                        "assets/img/img-aris/0001.png",
                        "assets/img/img-aris/0002.png",
                        "assets/img/img-aris/0003.png"
                                                ];

                    // TweenMax can tween any property of any object. We use this object to cycle through the array
                    var obj = {curImg: 0};

                    // create tween
                    var tween = TweenMax.to(obj, 1,
                        {
                            curImg: images.length - 1,  // animate propery curImg to number of images
                            roundProps: "curImg",               // only integers so it can be used as an array index
                            repeat: 0,                                  // repeat 3 times
                            immediateRender: true,          // load first image automatically
                            ease: Linear.easeNone,          // show every image the same ammount of time
                            onUpdate: function () {
                              $("#myimg").attr("src", images[obj.curImg]); // set the image source
                            }
                        }
                    );

                    // init controller
                    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

                    // build scene
                    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({duration: 10000})
                                    .setTween(tween)
                                    .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
                                    //.removeIndicators()
                                    .addTo(controller);

                </script>
```

Comment: In order to help you, we need to see some code :-)

Comment: oh i'm sorry 
ok i've edit my question